# Latexian not working with new El Capitan OS X

Tags: errors

For some reason, all of the compliing buttons are gone. I read

http://www.tug.org/mactex/UpdatingForElCapitan.pdf

But I can't implement the advice, because Library/TeX/ has no folder called "texbin". How do I get Latexian working again?

Comment: Install MacTeX 2015?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem was solved by an update of MacTeX.